# How to save the data when phone is locked via too many patterns attempted?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am using Samsung S2, due to my nephew attempting too many wrong patterns in my phone now it is locked and it is displaying "**Too Many Patterns Attempted sign in to your Google account**".

I want to know if I unlock it by using Google account, will it wipe out my all the data that is in my phone memory? If so, how can I unlock the phone without losing any data from my phone memory?

Comment: When your phone says `Too Many Patterns Attempted sign in to your Google account`, signing in with your Google account (even without Internet connectivity) will NOT wipe any data. It will only ask you to provide a chance to change the lock pattern.

Comment: But i have lost some contacts from my phone memory.it saved my data from my galary.